# parse json array which contains sql array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, parsing

My question: How can I parse a json array?

I send it like this:

```
$data= mysql_fetch_array($r);
header('Content-type: application/json');

?>              
{
    "check": "<?php echo $check?>",
    "productcode": "<?php echo $code?>",
     "values": [<?php echo $data?>]
}
<?php
```

on the ajax side I do this on the single values which works fine

```
success: function(data,textStatus){
    //return values
    identification=data.check;
```

if I want to access the array I do something like this and I get undefined

```
value=data.values[1];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yeh, I heard that yesterday
I really don't want to offend anybody.
Sorry, I never payd much attention, to those things on the left sight. I will do that from now on. I really did not know at first why I was offending anyone, because I always say thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode your array as JSON, too:

```
{
    "check": "<?php echo $check?>",
    "productcode": "<?php echo $code?>",
     "values": [<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>]
}
```

The easiest way is probably to put everything in a PHP array and serialize this as JSON:

```
$output = array(
    "check" => $check,
    "productcode" => $code,
    "values" => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

Then you can be sure that it is being encoded properly.

Comment: thanks, could you comment on the mysql_NUM, can I still get the values by name then, in ajax success function.

Comment: You could use mysql_fetch_assoc which returns an associative array. That means, that you then can access the columns in a row by its name in JavaScript (and not by its index). Just check the result and then you'll see what it does.

Comment: With msql_fetch_array, associative is the default, because I get my results by name, or both I get from @RC, s comment below.

Comment: Oh ok sorry. Well the manual said that MYSQL_NUM gives you a non associative array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data= mysql_fetch_array($r);
header('Content-type: application/json');

$json = array(
    'check' => $check,
    'productcode' => $code,
    'values' => $data
    );

print json_encode($json);
```

It's more tidy than printing the json manually. [json_encode](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) turns a PHP array into a json string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data= mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_NUM);
```

could correct the problem.

It would be helpful to get the json you get in the ajax part

Comment: what is it know then, an asociative?
is associative bad for parsing?

Comment: according to the doc, it's both associative and num